# Assertion `fp_ != 0' failed (RapidJSON)

Tags: c++, json, game-engine, sfml, rapidjson

I'm making a game engine that can load graphics from JSON and PNG files, and I've made some real progress. The only problem is, I can't figure out how to load multiple sprites at a time. I've tried many different approaches, but this is the one that I think is going to work. While compiled, though, the terminal gives me this error:

> Test: /home/thomas/Documents/project-repos/game/rapidjson/filereadstream.h:45: rapidjson::FileReadStream::FileReadStream(FILE*, char*, std::size_t): Assertion `fp_ != 0' failed.
>
> Aborted (core dumped)

I know that this usually means that the JSON file can't be found, but I've made sure that everything is in the working directory.

Here's my code:

*main.cpp:*

```
#include <iostream>
#include <unistd.h>
#include <string>
#include <SFML/Graphics.hpp>

// The universal include file.
#include "include.hpp"

int main() {

    // Declaration of the window.
    sf::RenderWindow window(sf::VideoMode(640, 320), "Test Game", sf::Style::Close);

    // Getting the background texture.
    sf::Texture bkgd;
    if(!bkgd.loadFromFile("../textures/generic.png")) {
        ErrorLog("1", "../game.log");
        window.close();
    }

    // Getting the map textures.
    sf::Texture map;
    if(!map.loadFromFile("../textures/textures.png")) {
        ErrorLog("2", "../game.log");
        window.close();
    }

    // Creating the background sprite.
    sf::Sprite bkgdSp;
    bkgdSp.setTexture(bkgd);

    // Local variable to check if fullscreen is activated.
    int fullScreen = 0;

    // The window loop.
    while(window.isOpen()) {

        // Local variable that keeps the current window size.
        sf::Vector2f winSize(window.getSize());

        // Local variables storing the window ratios.
        float scaleX = winSize.x / 640;
        float scaleY = winSize.y / 320;

        // Local variable to store the number of map tiles.
        int mapNum = LoadNumber("../locations.json");

        // Local array for the sprites.
        sf::Sprite mapSp;

        // Local array for the tiles.
        tile mapTile;

        // Load tile information.
        mapTile = LoadTile("../locations.json", 1);

        // Texture rectangle for the current sprite.
        sf::IntRect mapRect(GetFileCoordinates(mapTile.type).x, GetFileCoordinates(mapTile.type).y, GetFileWidth(mapTile.type), GetFileHeight(mapTile.type));

        // Setting the texture for the current sprite.
        mapSp.setTexture(map);
        mapSp.setTextureRect(mapRect);

        // Scaling and repositioning the current sprite.
        mapSp.setScale(scaleX, scaleY);
        mapSp.setPosition(mapTile.x * scaleX, mapTile.y * scaleY);


        // The event loop (only used to close the window.
        sf::Event event;
        while(window.pollEvent(event)) {
            if(event.type == sf::Event::Closed) {
                window.close();
            }
        }

        // Change window size if F1 is pressed.
        if(sf::Keyboard::isKeyPressed(sf::Keyboard::F1)) {
            if(fullScreen == 0) {
                window.create(sf::VideoMode(1280, 640), "Test Game", sf::Style::Close);
                fullScreen = 1;
            }else if(fullScreen == 1) {
                window.create(sf::VideoMode(640, 320), "Test Game", sf::Style::Fullscreen);
                fullScreen = 2;
            }else if(fullScreen == 2) {
                window.create(sf::VideoMode(640, 320), "Test Game", sf::Style::Close);
                fullScreen = 0;
            }
        }

        // Resizes the background to fit the window size.
        bkgdSp.setScale(scaleX, scaleY);

        // Drawing and displaying the window.
        window.clear();

        window.draw(bkgdSp);
        window.draw(mapSp);

        window.display();

        usleep(7000);
    }

    return 0;
}
```

*load.cpp:*

```
#include <iostream>
#include <SFML/System.hpp>
#include "rapidjson/document.h"
#include "rapidjson/filereadstream.h"

// The universal include file.
#include "include.hpp"

using namespace rapidjson;

// Function that loads tile values from the locations file.
tile LoadTile(std::string fileName, int number) {
    tile output;

    FILE* file = fopen(fileName.c_str(), "r");

    char buffer[10000];
    FileReadStream stream(file, buffer, 10000);

    Document doc;
    doc.ParseStream(stream);

    std::string input = std::to_string(number);

    Value& tileNumber = doc[input.c_str()];

    output.x = tileNumber[0]["x"].GetInt();
    output.y = tileNumber[1]["y"].GetInt();
    output.type = tileNumber[2]["type"].GetString();

    return output;
}

// Function that gets the current tile type's x and y coordinates.
sf::Vector2f GetFileCoordinates(std::string type) {
    sf::Vector2f output;

    FILE* file = fopen("../textures.json", "r");

    char buffer[10000];
    FileReadStream stream(file, buffer, 10000);

    Document doc;
    doc.ParseStream(stream);

    Value& typeNumber = doc[type.c_str()];

    output.x = typeNumber[0]["x"].GetInt();
    output.y = typeNumber[1]["y"].GetInt();

    return output;
}

// Function that gets the number of objects in the current map file.
int LoadNumber(std::string fileName) {
    FILE* file = fopen(fileName.c_str(), "r");

    char buffer[10000];
    FileReadStream stream(file, buffer, 10000);

    Document doc;
    doc.ParseStream(stream);

    int objCount = 1;
    std::string strCount = std::to_string(objCount);
    while(doc.HasMember(strCount.c_str())) {
        objCount++;
        strCount = std::to_string(objCount);
    }

    return objCount - 1;
}

// Function that gets the current tile type's width.
int GetFileWidth(std::string type) {
    int output;

    FILE* file = fopen("../textures.json", "r");

    char buffer[10000];
    FileReadStream stream(file, buffer, 10000);

    Document doc;
    doc.ParseStream(stream);

    Value& typeNumber = doc[type.c_str()];

    output = typeNumber[2]["width"].GetInt();

    return output;
}

// Function that gets the current tile type's height.
int GetFileHeight(std::string type) {
    int output;

    FILE* file = fopen("../textures.json", "r");

    char buffer[10000];
    FileReadStream stream(file, buffer, 10000);

    Document doc;
    doc.ParseStream(stream);

    Value& typeNumber = doc[type.c_str()];

    output = typeNumber[3]["height"].GetInt();

    return output;
}
```

*include.hpp:*

```
#include <iostream>
#include <SFML/Graphics.hpp>
#include "rapidjson/document.h"

// Public struct declaring the "tile" data type. Uses the same characteristics as the tile locations file.
struct tile {
    int x;
    int y;
    std::string type;
};

// In load.cpp.
tile LoadTile(std::string fileName, int number);
sf::Vector2f GetFileCoordinates(std::string type);
int LoadNumber(std::string fileName);
int GetFileWidth(std::string type);
int GetFileHeight(std::string type);

// In log.cpp
void ErrorLog(std::string code, std::string fileName);
```

*locations.json:*

```
{
    "1": [{
        "x": 32
    }, {
        "y": 32
    }, {
        "type": "water_c"
    }],

    "2": [{
        "x": 32
    }, {
        "y": 64
    }, {
        "type": "dirt_c"
    }]
}
```

*textures.json:*

```
{
    "grass_c": [{
        "x": 0
    }, {
        "y": 0
    }, {
        "width": 32
    }, {
        "height": 32
    }],

    "water_c": [{
        "x": 32
    }, {
        "y": 0
    }, {
        "width": 32
    }, {
        "height": 32
    }],

    "sand_c": [{
        "x": 64
    }, {
        "y": 0
    }, {
        "width": 32
    }, {
        "height": 32
    }],

    "dirt_c": [{
        "x": 96
    }, {
        "y": 0
    }, {
        "width": 32
    }, {
        "height": 32
    }],

    "wood_c": [{
        "x": 128
    }, {
        "y": 0
    }, {
        "width": 32
    }, {
        "height": 32
    }],

    "brick_c": [{
        "x": 160
    }, {
        "y": 0
    }, {
        "width": 32
    }, {
        "height": 32
    }]
}
```

Any mention of "ErrorLog()" is in another file, which has already been tested. Compiling with CMake (gcc) on Xubuntu 16.10 if anyone can help. Thanks.

**EDIT**

I've added new code to all of my JSON functions:

```
FILE* file = fopen("../textures.json", "r");
if(file == 0) {
    std::cout << "GetFileHeight failed to load the file." << std::endl;
}
```

... changing it to fit every function. "GetFileHeight" is causing the error, it seems. I think it might be about opening the file, and not closing it before reading it again? I'm not sure.

Comment: "While compiled, though, the terminal gives me this error: ..."  You mean, like, compiling is causing a core dump?!

Comment: Yeah, I should have been more specific. It doesn't give me compiler errors, it's giving me an error after the executable has been created.

Answer (score 2):

Your error seems to happen due to this part (or one of the repetitions) of your code failing:

```
FILE* file = fopen(fileName.c_str(), "r");

char buffer[10000];
FileReadStream stream(file, buffer, 10000);
```

You should always check, whether `fopen()` could actually open the file. If it failed, `file` will be set to `0` (or `NULL` to be precise), which will trigger the assertion in the constructor for `FileReadStream`, because you're passing `NULL`, which isn't a valid file pointer (`FILE*`).